# Does this mean what I want it to mean?

Tags: grammar

**The light glared white off the sheeny floor.**

Can I write this to mean "The floor, receiving the light, reflected it back to the eyes of the author, which looked white to him."?

this "glare white off" part bugs me as I write this.

Comment: Why is this in ELL? This almost seems like [english.se] or [writers.se].

Comment: I'm even confused by your meaning. Is the light white or is the floor?

Comment: @Martin Neither. The *glare of the reflection* (of the light, which is bouncing off the floor) is what's white. The light and floor combine to produce the appearance of whiteness.

Comment: I think the meaning is the light glared, and appeared white - there's not necessarily a person to perceive this, but if there had been, that is what they would have seen.

Comment: The "glared white off" part doesn't bother me; I understood the image right away. "Shiny" is probably more common than "sheeny," but they both work. "Polished" would work well too, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would word this differently:

> The light **produced a white glare** on the shiny floor.

Comment: Your sentence wasn't entire incorrect, but not quite "there" at first glance. Additionally it's a bit poetic in its structure and tenor. "glare" is more commonly used with the meaning "to give someone an angry look." Also, "sheeny" is a valid word, however it's also a derogatory name for a Jew.

Comment: The newly risen sun already glared white off the broad waters. I found this in a book.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Again, your sentence is also correct, but like this example, it's quite literary and poetic. I just offered a more colloquial interpretation of the same thing.

Comment: So it doesn't mean that the sun is white but that the reflection is white?

Comment: Exactly, when you look out over the water, you have to shield your eyes from the white glare produced by the sun.

Comment: Sorry about what??? This is a great question :)

Comment: The quote from @user's first comment is from *[Devil Water](http://books.google.com/books?id=XCouJtOgI94C&pg=PT371&lpg=PT371&dq=%22The+newly+risen+sun+already+glared+white+off+the+broad+waters%22&source=bl&ots=GYdRreE57B&sig=Q3Y3tweMpPXrETkrvaXjwYaQ-o0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0OXkU9eqKMP2oASok4GIAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20newly%20risen%20sun%20already%20glared%20white%20off%20the%20broad%20waters%22&f=false)*, a historical novel (involving real figures and events, but dramatized) set in the early 1700s. Thus the usage is likely to be archaic.

Answer (score 3):

> The light glared white off the sheeny floor.

This is an unusual construction, but is acceptable with a bit of literary license. Here, *glare* is used as a transitive verb, with *white* as its object. This construction tells the reader that the whiteness is a product of the reflection, and not an inherent quality of the light. It's not *white light*, it's *a white glare produced by the light's reflection*.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glare) lists this usage, but marks it as archaic. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glare#Verb) also includes the transitive definition, but notice that the example quotes Milton, who wrote in the 1600s. Oxford, Collins, Longman and several others define the relevant sense as strictly intransitive, and many mark it as requiring an adverbial modifier.

Thus, as I said, it's acceptable, but not standard modern English. And that's OK, as long as the diction isn't out of place. If it matches the general tone of your writing, go for it. If this is appearing in, say, a colloquial conversation about internet memes, it's not appropriate.

Comment: white is not an object, it is like "shine white" this is just a complement.

Comment: @user Objects are complements, though not all complements are objects. But if you want the sentence as given to mean what you want, then you need the archaic usage. The fact that it sounds weird but not obviously wrong to you (and to me also) is a strong indication that this is the case. If white is a subject complement, then the light is white (not what you mean). If it's a verb complement, then it should be an adverb (*whitely*). *Shine white* has exactly the same grammatical issues and "feel" as *glare white*.